# How can I get estimatedRevenue per video using youtube-api?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

**What I want to do：**

I want to get the estimated revenue per video.

**What I tried：**

The "estimatedRevenue" can be obtained for each channel.

I don't know how to get it for each video.

**Reference：**

YouTube Analytics API

https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/data_model

Reports: Query | YouTube Analytics and Reporting APIs

https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query?hl=ja